# On checked how to change the color of radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How I can change the color of a radio button after selecting it?
I'm using this code but it's not working for me.

```
    <div class="container3">
        <label class="columnName" style="margin-bottom:7px">Analytics</label><span style="color: red !important; display: inline; float: none;">    *</span><br></br>
        <label class="btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="first" id="radio1" value="SQL" style="margin-left: 10px"></input><span style="margin-left:20px">SQL </span>  
        </label><br></br>
        <label class="btn-primary">
            <input type="radio" name="first" id="radio2" value="Python" style="margin-left: 10px"></input><span style="margin-left:20px">Python </span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

And my CSS code is:

```
           .container3 input[type="radio"]:checked 
                   {
                    background-color: #ff0000;
                 }
```

But this is not working for me.
Can someone please help me to figure out this without implementing custom images or use of custom Javascript library? Thank you

Comment: A radio button is a native element specific to each OS/browser. There is no way to change its color/style, unless you want to implement custom images or use a custom Javascript library which includes images.

Comment: Check out https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp to build your own radio-elements.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want something like this?

```css
/* The container */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default radio button */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom radio button */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */


/* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #ff9999;
}

/* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
  background: #ff9999;
}

/* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */
.container .checkmark:after {
    top: 9px;
    left: 9px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Custom Radio Buttons</h1>
<label class="container">Php
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Java
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Python
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Sql
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```